# Creating a keypair through the RPC API

Tags: cleos, rpc, api, keys

Is there a way to create a keypair through the [RPC API](https://eosio.github.io/eos/group__eosiorpc.html#details)? Previously, I've been doing this with `cleos wallet create_key` or `cleos create key` but now I'm building an application that needs to do this programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would reconsider this approach because it is possible to **expose your/the users private key** if you rely on a thrid party to create the key. Even if the third party behaves correct, due to transmissions you were also likely to be exposed to **middleman attacks**.

Also currently there is **no RPC call** for safely creating key-pairs via 3rd party available.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `nodeos`, the RPC is start on the port number 8888.

You can generate new keypair by following method:

Note:- Creates a key within the specified wallet, wallet must be opened and unlocked.

Parameters are: 
1.name of the wallet to create key in; 
2. type of key to create, currently that support two values: K1 and R1

Run following command in terminal:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/wallet/create_key -X POST -d '["wallet_name","K1"]'
```

This command will return the public key of the created key:

```
EOS6GZE1xeo6jX2AtP2Z6WTcxawQMH7cyYMNpG6Q3q7s514zyRhgo
```

If it gives error `wallet doesn't exist`, then create wallet by RPC call:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888/v1/wallet/create -X POST -d '"wallet_name"'
```

Then apply first command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use a Block Producer API endpoint to do the HTTP RPC calls for wallet creation? If you run your own test node, you can pretty much follow the examples that are shown in the reference you mentioned. They are all curl examples but they can be implemented using any web client.

Comment: The wallet can easily be created through an RPC call; however, no RPC call exists for creating keypairs nor accounts.

Comment: Agreed. Can you use ideas from https://github.com/nsjames/Scatter/blob/master/src/cryptography/EOSKeygen.js